# Manipulação de Datas Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Preciso pegar uma data de um input e acrescentar alguns anos nela e apresentar o e resultado em outra label.

Ex = 01/01/2017 - Data Selecionada pelo usuário
     01/01/2020 - Data calculada pelo js

Comment: Você quer resolver o problema com Javascript ou com C#?

Answer (score 0):

Um jeito de fazer isso é da seguinte forma:

```
var d = new Date(2017,0,1);
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var c = new Date(year + 3, month, day)
// => Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora Padrão de Buenos Aires)
```

Assim pode ser alterado tanto o ano, mês ou dia da data de acordo com a necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" id="ini" value="28/03/2017"><br>
<input type="text" id="fim"><br>

<script>

var anos = 3;

var dataNoCampo = document.getElementById('ini').value.split('/');
var ini        = new Date(dataNoCampo[2],dataNoCampo[1],dataNoCampo[0]);
var fim    = new Date(ini.getTime() + (anos * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 365));

document.getElementById('fim').value = fim.getDate() + "/" + fim.getMonth() + "/" + fim.getFullYear();

</script>
```